# Sort array of 50 000 objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, datatable, large-data

I need to sort an array of objects in javascript(angular project).

My object is fairly simple, just a single layer of some strings and ints:

```
{
    id: 7683,
    base: "example",
    value: 1000000,
    poster: "example",
    price: 100,
    itemCount: 49
}
```

There are going to be 50 000 of these objects, and I'm displaying them in a table, where the user should be able to sort by any of the properties (I'm paginating them to save resources during rendering).

My current implementation is the base javascript sort alg with a custom sort func:

```
this.myList.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id)
```

Currently this takes around 25 seconds, which is not the user experience I'm after. I tested a datatable implementation, which seemed to work quickly, so I'm trying to find out why mine is not as fast.

What is the fastest way to accomplish my sort? Do I need to write a custom quick sort? If so, do you mind explaining what about the default sort with a custom function makes it slower than something I might write myself? Thanks

Edit:

Thanks to those who highlighted that it should not be taking this long. I was not sure of a reasonable timeframe for a sort like this. After creating some tests cases it seems it was the painting/rendering of the UI elements that was taking the time(despite chrome debugger saying it was all scripting, maybe my understanding of this is incorrect). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to spread the sorting job to the Web Worker. I did the same exact sort calculations on my project and used web worker for it.

Comment: the better question is, why do you sort 50k items? what kind of app is this?

Comment: How does it take 25 seconds?

Comment: 25 seconds to sort 50000 items looks like a bubblesort performance. Are you sure pagination is not working during data-fetch for sorting?

Comment: Are you sure it is the sort and not something else?

Comment: Thanks to those who highlighted that it should not be taking this long. I was not sure of a reasonable timeframe for a sort like this. After creating some tests cases it seems it was the painting/rendering of the UI elements that was taking the time(despite chrome debugger saying it was all scripting, maybe my understanding of this is incorrect). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Fyi, I do not own the API, I have no choice but to sort this data on the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to you using [mat-sort](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview#changing-the-sort-order) its very fast.

Another things you can do to improve sorting:

1. If you can - sorting by server is way more faster and easier.
2. Check how long it takes to the API request to fully get the data - "25 seconds" may cause by slow network / file format (like string that need to be parsed / gzip and more)... and not the sort itself.
3. Render the data only after the data is already sorted (like sorting in rxjs pipe / *ngIf...).
4. You can use [trackBy](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) it can speed the process by a little.
5. You can save the data of the first paginator page in localStorage - then in the second time you can render to the user the first page (from localStorage) - while you sorting "behind the curtain" and rerendering the full data.
6. There is a few more solution it depend on the app you've got - for example if its a small app with related data - you can sort the data during app initialization [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER)
7. Angular material [table/paginator/sort](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-http) can speed up the ordering a lot - this link example is examine 23,575 objects.

Answer (score 0):

try some solution like quicksort Algorithm:
https://github.com/duereg/js-algorithms/blob/master/lib/algorithms/11-sorting/quickSort.js